# Get data from parent row that has a child row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a datatble like this:

[image]

This is my html code:

```
<div class="table-responsive-lg table-responsive-md">
        <table id="table" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="primary">
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Solicitante</th>
                    <th>Dia de solicitud</th>
                    <th>Estatus</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And this is my javascript code:

I fill the data table like this way:
[image]

I made the child row as next way:

[image]

Comment: Where does the required I'd available?you are appending it next to parent row right?

Comment: Yes the id is part of the parent row

Comment: Show where you are calling format function?